# Json object with duplicate keys in node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, object, duplicates

I have an array  ["10","20"]
from this array i need to form an object as below.  The elements in the array should point to "id" field in the json obejct. If there are more elements in the array that many times id field should come in the response.

input: ["10","20"]
expected response

```
{
id: "10",
id: "20:,
value1: true,// this key and value need to be hardcoded
value2: false //this key and value need to be hardcoded
}
```

I tried using the below option but it is not allowing duplicate keys in the response

```
var mapped = array.map(item => ({ "id": item.key }) );
console.log(mapped)
var newObj = Object.assign({}, ...mapped );
```

It will be a great help if anyone can help with this

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot have duplicate keys in Object
2. Every keys in object are unique while the values can be duplicate but not the keys
3. So if you have key id:'10' then the next time any value with obj["id"]=20 will overwrite the value 10